How to set up DataTables pagination with a POST request
I've scoured the DataTables documentation, particularly here and here, but I can't wrap my head around how to send a data model in my POST request and get back the necessary fields (draw, recordsTotal, and recordsFiltered) in my response for pagination.
I'm pretty sure that the problem lies in my ajax.data or ajax.dataSrc configuration, but I'm stumped. I'd appreciate any help anyone can offer.
Here's an example of the model being sent to POST:
        let model = {};
        model.entityid = entityid;
        model.entitytypeid = entitytypeid;
        model.fromDate = fromDateVal;
        model.toDate = toDateVal;
        model.vins = $('#searchVIN').val();
        model.violations = $('#selViolation option:checked').val();

Here's my JavaScript to generate the DataTable:
    let dailyScanTable = $('#dailyScanTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.example.com/Advertising/AdvertisingDailyScanPost',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: model,
            dataSrc: function (json) {
                if (json == undefined) {
                    // error handling
                    return false;
                } else {
                    const totalListing = json.Summary.TotalListings;
                    let numPriceMissing;
                    // set some more variables to be populated

                    if (json.Summary == undefined || json.Summary.TotalListings == undefined) {
                        // error handling
                        return false;
                    }

                    let returnModel = {};
                    returnModel.dailyScanJson = json.Violations.Rows;
                    returnModel.recordsTotal = json.Summary.TotalListings;
                    returnModel.recordsFiltered = 0;
                    switch (model.violations) {
                        case 'Missing Price':
                            returnModel.recordsFiltered = getRecordsFiltered(json.Summary.Violations, 'Missing Price');
                            break;
                        // etc.
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    // get various totals, subtotals, and some DOM manipulations                    

                    // Return contents used in DataTable
                    // THIS is the only way I've been able to populate
                    // the DataTable, but it breaks pagination. :-(
                    return returnModel.dailyScanJson; 

                }
            },
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'vin' },
            { data: 'Violation' },
            { data: 'url' },
            { data: 'ScanDate' },
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                visible: false,
                targets: [3],
            },
            {
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    const modifiedURL = data.replace('https://', '').replace('/', '<br />/');
                    return `<a href="${data}" target="_blank">${modifiedURL}</a>;
                },
                targets: [2],
            }
        ],
        paging: true,
    })

Here's the result of my Ajax call (as copied from Postman):
{
    "Violations": {
        "RowCount": 515,
        "CurrentPage": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "Rows": [
            {
                "vin": "19XFB2F86EE015081",
                "Violation": "Has Open Recall",
                "url": "https://www.example.com/used-St+Albans-2014-Honda-Civic-EX-19XFB2F86EE015081",
                "ScanDate": "2024-04-21T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "vin": "1C4BJWDG5DL616992",
                "Violation": "Has Open Recall",
                "url": "https://www.example.com/used-St+Albans-2013-Jeep-Wrangler-Unlimited+Sport-1C4BJWDG5DL616992",
                "ScanDate": "2024-04-21T00:00:00"
            },
            {
                "vin": "1C4BJWDG9EL157029",
                "Violation": "Has Open Recall",
                "url": "https://www.example.com/used-Charleston-2014-Jeep-Wrangler-Unlimited+Sport-1C4BJWDG9EL157029",
                "ScanDate": "2024-04-21T00:00:00"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "Summary": {
        "TotalListings": 1772,
        "Violations": [
            {
                "Name": "Has Open Recall",
                "Total": 492
            },
            {
                "Name": "Missing Price",
                "Total": 23
            },
            {
                "Name": "No Cookie ConsentBanner",
                "Total": 0
            },
            {
                "Name": "Price Clarification Notice Missing",
                "Total": 0
            },
            {
                "Name": "Price Clarification Closure Missing",
                "Total": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}


There is too much info missing from the question to provide any answer that does not rely on too much guesswork. But, here are some notes:  (a) Don't use data: model. As described here, this will only contain the data defined when the table is first initlaized , which is why it is useful for static data only. Instead use the functional form for the data option. (b) But also, do you understand that DataTables itself will populate the sent data typically needed by the server?

Your let model = {}; looks like it discards all of that. Instead, you should be appending your extra data to the data provided by DataTables. (c) The postman data you show looks nothing like the data response expected by DataTables. It's the server's job to build a response which matches what DataTables can consume.

If done correctly, you would not even need dataSrc - which is only needed if you have to massage the returned JSON into the structure expected by DataTables, or tell DataTables where to find the array of row data in the response. Apologies if these notes are telling you things you already know - but these are my suggestions based on what I see in the question.
